# How to specify multiple OR conditions in android (sqlite3)?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to know how to specify something like in my database adapter:

```
Select * from _myTable WHERE _columnValue IN ('2','3','4');
```

Is there a way to use any of the existing query methods specified in [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)? I can write the query in pure sql, but wondering whether there is a better (and easier) way to accomplish what I am after.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is possible:

```
String[] args=new String[] {"2", "3", "4"};
Cursor cursor=database.query(myTable, 
         myTableColumns,
         "_columnValue in (?, ?, ?)",
         args,
         null, null, null);
```